# How can I access the startup arguments from within in a gradle script?

Tags: gradle

In a gradle script I am creating and then starting (i.e. exec'íng) new gradle scripts.
During developing and debugging it would be nice if I could pass on certain options (like -i(nfo), -debug or --stacktrace) on to the children scripts when starting them.

Is there a way to query the startup arguments of the running gradle script from within that script, so that I can pass them on to an exec? I googled around a while but found no hint, yet. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can come up with is [StartParameter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html):

> `StartParameter` defines the configuration used by a Gradle instance to execute a build. The properties of `StartParameter` generally correspond to the command-line options of Gradle.

You can obtain an instance of the current build via [Gradle.getStartParameter()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getStartParameter--):

```
project.getGradle().getStartParameter()
```

Comment: Fair enough. That allowed me at least to extract the logging level as well as the stacktrace setting and passing it down to the daughter script. Thanks for the hint plus the pointer!